# Extract ggplot from a nested dataframe

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr

I have created a set of ggplots using a grouped dataframe and the map function and I would like to extract the plots to be able to manipulate them individually.

```
library(tidyverse)

plot <- function(df, title){
  df %>% ggplot(aes(class)) +
    geom_bar() + 
    labs(title = title)
}

plots <- mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>%  nest() %>% 
  mutate(plots= map(.x=data, ~plot(.x, manufacturer)))

nissan <- plots %>% filter(manufacturer == "nissan") %>% pull(plots) 
nissan

nissan + labs(title = "Nissan")
```

In this case, "nissan" is a list object and I am not able to manipulate it. How do I extract the ggplot?

Comment: Your `nissan` object is a list. So do `nissan[[1]] + labs(title = "Nissan")`

Comment: Thanks! That was simple.
Is it somehow possible to do it in the pipe? 
plots %>% filter(manufacturer == "nissan") %>% pull(plots)

Comment: Yep. Do. `plots %>% filter(manufacturer == "nissan") %>% pull(plots) %>% .[[1]]` or `... %>% purrr::pluck(1)`

Comment: You can use extract2(list number) to extract a list item. So, to put all your code into one pipe ```mpg %>% group_by(manufacturer) %>%  nest() %>% 
    mutate(plots= map(.x=data, ~plot(.x, manufacturer))) %>% filter(manufacturer == "nissan") %>% pull(plots) %>%  extract2(1) + labs(title = "Nissan")```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of data structures, I think retaining a `tibble` (or `data.frame`) is suboptimal with respect to the illustrated usage. If you have one plot per manufacturer, and you plan to access them by manufacturer, then I would recommend to `transmute` and then `deframe` out to a `list` object.

That is, I would find it more conceptually clear here to do something like:

```
library(tidyverse)

plot <- function(df, title){
  df %>% ggplot(aes(class)) +
    geom_bar() + 
    labs(title = title)
}

plots <- mpg %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% nest() %>% 
  transmute(plot=map(.x=data, ~plot(.x, manufacturer))) %>%
  deframe()

plots[['nissan']]

plots[['nissan']] + labs(title = "Nissan")
```

Otherwise, if you want to keep the tibble, another option similar to what has been suggested in the comments is to use a `first()` after the `pull`.